# Not able to debug AWS SAM hello world application

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, aws-sam

I am new to python/pycharm and AWS SAM applications. My company has created a few AWS SAM apps and they have worked previously on my machine. Now I am unable to get even the example hello world AWS SAM solution to run on my machine. I'm not sure if this is a docker or pycharm issue. When I try to debug the application, this is the error I receive:

Fetching lambci/lambda:python3.8 Docker container image...............
Mounting C:\Dev\git\ULServices\TestRun.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
/var/lang/bin/python3.8: can't open file '/tmp/lambci_debug_files/pydevd.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I am on Windows 10 and have the latest version of Docker/PyCharm/AWS SAM CLI

Comment: Having the exact same issue.  No idea what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Docker issue. Release 2.2.0.5 on Apr 2, 2020 fixed the issue. From their release notes: 
Fixed a bug where opening a read-only file would fail with an Operation not permitted error. Fixes docker/for-win#6016 and docker/for-win#6017.

I have turned off automatic updates since this is what initially caused the issue for me since it was working in a previous version.